# multi-second delay when using a jtapi provider from two different processes

Tags: cisco-jtapi

I am using Cisco Jtapi version 7.1(3.10000)-1.  When a jtapi provider (from one process) starts monitoring events for users on CUCM, another provider (from a second process) appears to block until the first provider receives the initial state of all users after which the second provider starts receiving its events.  Is this the intended behavior?  Can it be modified through some jtapi config or API call? Any insights on troubleshooting this issue would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was due to a throttling config parameter within CUCM - increasing the limit in CUCM or implementing your own rate limiting solution can bypass CUCM throttling.